# 3x3 Wordsquare Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, word-square

> *My first is in a gift,
>
>   A representation of what you are.*
>
> *My second not so much a gift,
>
>   But a representation of what you were.*
>
> *Although these hints may not mean much,
>
>   I am confident that you can count on me!*

**Hint 1:**

> The second one is like a bonus if you know the first.

Comment: +1 for destroying the culture of simple Wordsquare Riddles! Is this really a 2x2?

Comment: i think its a 3x3

Comment: Thanks! I'll specify the size as a hint once more time has passed, but until then... Keep on guessing~

Comment: You were right @starkgurl (y)

Comment: @JFox YAYYY hahahh!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is the answer but I want to give it a try! HAHA.
I think the answer is:

> E A T
> A T E
> T E N

My first is in a gift,
A representation of what you are.

> In a gift or in "a present".
> The word EAT is in "a present"
> ALSO You are what you **eat** !! (As mentioned by @JFox  :) )

My second not so much a gift,
But a representation of what you were.

> ATE is the past tense of eat

Although these hints may not mean much,
I am confident that you can count on me!

> The keyword being count- TEN is a number

Comment: WOOOO YOU GOT IT!

Comment: In case you wanted to know what the first crucial stanza meant. It was to hint "present tense" and the quote "you are what you eat"

Comment: aw man! makes more sense now!! I'll put it in my answer!

Comment: OoooH "you are what you eat" is very clever

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

The size of this Wordsquare is

> ..either 2×2 (as explicitly said) , 3×3 (if the last stanza means something) or 4×4 (if the last two lines each are up to something

*My first is in a gift, a representation of what you are*

> This may refer to **present**, which refer to the gift and the word *are*.

*My second not so much a gift,
But a representation of what you were.*

> Using the same logic, this refers to **past**

But that is way too long a word for a Wordsquare! Well,

> It can be fitted using the [Japanese letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53116/37926?stw=2), or something like that. I must stop here, since I know nothing about Japanese, and I might be completely off-track.

Comment: You are definitely on track, except for the last one. (Saya juga orang Jakarta :P)

Comment: Op just said he was from Jakarta/indonesia so.... better learn that language first haha

Comment: @stackreader As a matter of fact, Indonesian is my mother tongue! But believe me, it won't help. Indonesian is the simplest language I know in the matter of writing and pronunciation, and it uses ABC too.

Comment: @stackreader sono tori

Comment: oh, ok, well it won't be Japanese either, in which I am fluent. Past is (ka)(ko), present is (gen)(zai)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> A M 
>  M E

My thinking:

> A gift can be a *present*, and the present tense "I am" represents what you are. "Me" can refer to who you are or who you were: "I was (me)". Additionally, the last line explicitly states that you can count on *me*.

Edit: was revealed to be a 3x3 right as I posted this, will have to reconsider

Edit: 3x3 solution

> EGO 
>  GOD 
>  ODD

Reasoning this time:

> "Ego" is the Latin for "I", as in "I am." In the Bible, God told Moses "I am who I am." Aaaaand you can "count on" odd numbers.

... Okay, it's a bit of a stretch.

Bonus Guardians of the Galaxy 2 spoilers explanation:

> "Ego" was the villain in GotG2, and he had godlike powers. He was also a bit odd.

Comment: +1 ! This would be the answer if it was 2x2, but in case you missed it, I updated the title to "3x3 Wordsquare Riddle"

Comment: Yeah, immediately saw it!

Comment: @JFox updated my answer!! :)

Comment: Sorry but that's not the answer :(